# Writing a regular expression for Google Analytics to check if url starts with certain url and also contain certain parameter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up a Goal for Google Analytics for a certain page pattern containing a subpage AND a parameter value.

If I have the url: http://www.domain-name.com/page-title/?sort=0&make%5B%5D=0.123&make%5B%5D=0.345&make%5B%5D=0.456&exterior_colour%5B%5D=4

What would the correct regex pattern be to check if we're currently at /page-title/ **and** the "make" parameter value equals 0.123 ?

Between /page-title/ and the parameter there may be any other parameters / characters aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the GA reports this is how i would do it:

```
  ^\/page\-title\/.*make.*\=0\.123
```

- ^ Begins with
- \ Makes the next character NOT a special character
- .* Matches any value

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood from your question

```
http:\/\/www\.domain-name\.com\/page-title\/.*?make%5B%5D=0.123
```